# How to Apply Query Filtering for JSON list like structure in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Django has support for jsonfield using postgres.

Below is the example for filtering results based on JSON key, value match.

```
OBJ1  : m1 = Movies.objects.create(movie_name='inception',movies_json_data{"review": "Mind Blowing", "rating": 5}   
OBJ2  :  m2 = Movies.objects.create(movie_name='joker',movies_json_data{"review": "horror", "rating": 4}   

>>> Movies.objects.filter(movies_json_data__rating=5)
<QuerySet [<Movies: Inception>]>
```

How do i perform filter query when data is in a list like JSON structure?

```
movies_json_data=[{"review": "horror", "rating": 4},{"review":"horror-with-scify","rating":"4.5"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

For one movie, you can do the following:

```
kwargs = {
    'movies_json_data__{}'.format('review'): 'horror',
    'movies_json_data__{}'.format('rating'): 4
}

Movies.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

So basically, you can now write a for loop and do the general approach. Let's suppose that you want to do an `OR` filter so you get the movies that match any of the filters

```
from django.db.models import Q
q_objects = Q()

for data in movies_json_data:
    kwargs = {}
    for k, v in data.items():
        kwargs['movies_json_data__{}'.format(k)] = v
    q_objects.add(Q(**kwargs), Q.OR)
queryset = Movie.objects.filter(q_objects)
```